# How to format output messages for Bot-framework for python sdk?

Tags: python, botframework, chatbot, markup, microsoft-teams

I am trying to use an output from custom function as a message for my chatbot output. I am using the sample cookiecutter **echo** template provided at this link.

What are the methods available to format the output that is visible in the chat. Such as Bold, Italic etc. And also how can i use different formats. As in future the out output of **my_foo** will be json.

[Echo Bot Python sdk template](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/tree/master/generators/app/templates/echo)

**Custom Function**

```
def my_foo(text):
     return text.upper()
```

**Bot Function**

```
class MyBot(ActivityHandler):
    # See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.

    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        await turn_context.send_activity(f"Upper Case  { my_foo(turn_context.activity.text }")

    async def on_members_added_activity(
        self,
        members_added: ChannelAccount,
        turn_context: TurnContext
    ):
        for member_added in members_added:
            if member_added.id != turn_context.activity.recipient.id:
                await turn_context.send_activity("Hello and welcome!")
```

If there is a documentation clarifying this or some basic steps that can be referred to that will be perfect.

Comment: Message formatting is channel-specific functionality, so at minimum you will need to specify what channel you're using. In the meantime you can find message-formatting documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-create-messages#message-text-and-formatting

Comment: Thanks for that comment. I am currently targeting MS teams as my channel. I will read the documentation shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information you need about formatting messages in Teams is [right here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-message-format). You use either Markdown or XML. I'm showing you how to set the optional text_format property of the activities, but Teams is smart enough to infer the format even if you don't set that property.

```
from botbuilder.schema import TextFormatTypes

. . .

async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
    markdown_reply = MessageFactory.text(
        f"Here is *italic* and **bold** with Markdown")
    xml_reply = MessageFactory.text(
        f"Here is <i>italic</i> and <b>bold</b> with XML")

    # markdown_reply.text_format = TextFormatTypes.markdown
    # xml_reply.text_format = TextFormatTypes.xml

    await turn_context.send_activity(markdown_reply)
    await turn_context.send_activity(xml_reply)
```

[image: Teams]

Comment: Great! Thank you for the detailed response @Kyle Delaney.